# Get two points which are perpendicular to a vector

Tags: javascript, vector, openlayers

Hi i'm having trouble figuring out how to create a vector which is perpendicular to another. `[-0.17640, 51.426700], [0.17640, 51.796700]` this is the first vector and i'm trying to create a perpendicular line which goes straight through the middle of it. This is what iv done so far but the line is not the correct angle.

```
startPosition = [-0.17640, 51.426700];
endPosition = [0.17640, 51.796700];

var midPoint = [];
midPoint[0] = (startPosition[0] + endPosition [0]) / 2;
midPoint[1] = (startPosition[1] + endPosition [1]) / 2;

positions[0] = midPoint;
positions[1] = [startPosition[1], startPosition[0] * -1];
positions[2] = [endPosition[0], endPosition[1]];
```

[image: This is what i have so far]

Comment: `pitch = sin(90 - arcsin(pitch))`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to get the 2D vector perpendicular to another 2D vector you can simply swap the X and Y components and negate the new Y component. So { x, y } becomes { y | -x }.

Midpoint:  [(x1 + x2)/2,( y1 + y2)/2]

Take a look at https://www.wikihow.com/Find-the-Perpendicular-Bisector-of-Two-Points

Comment: i need to get two points though, one either side of the line and the line needs to intersect at the midpoint. How would i be able to do that using this

Comment: Updated with a link

Comment: i did this and the direction of the line is still not 90 degrees to the original vector

Comment: if you are doing it in WGS84/mercator coordinates (lat, lon) remember that that lines aren't on a cartesian plan context, there are no straight lines on a sphere..

Comment: Ah okay is there anyway around this as that's what i'm working with?